# How can get friends list from facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.3

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am using Facebook sdk 3.5.3 for iOS,
There are various sample project available for iphone sdk. But I dont need that I want to know how can i get the list of friends with their details including birthdays without opening FBFriendPickerViewController.

1) I want all my friends facebook id, Date of birth.

2) And also I want to post comment in my friends wall.

Please suggest me some answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely get it using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userid/friends?fields=work&access_token=ACCESSTOKENHERE
```

or by caliing an object `/me/friends`, you can get list of facebook friends

Following is the list of permission to access friend's info

friends_birthday
friends_about_me
friends_activities
friends_checkins
friends_education_history
friends_events
friends_games_activity
friends_groups
friends_hometown
friends_interests
friends_likes
friends_location
friends_notes
friends_online_presence
friends_photo_video_tags 
friends_photos 
friends_videos
friends_relationship_details
friends_relationships
friends_religion_politics
friends_status
friends_subscriptions
friends_website
friends_work_history

Comment: Hi can u please tell me how can i post wishes in friends wall

Comment: I'm sorry! What do you mean by post wishes?

Comment: I like to post some comments on my friends Fb timeline. But I dont know how to post comments in my friends fb wall. Is there is any url for that

Comment: yes, once you get your friend's fb id you can use graphStreamPublish(selectedFriendIDs[i]); to post on friend's wall